# Disocrd.py Trying to make a discord bot that detects multiple words

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So basically I'm trying to make a bot that does some random stuff, one of them is detecting "bad" and "bot in the same sentence and replying to it

This is what have for that section

```
if message.author.bot:
    return
if "bot" and 'bad' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send("You are aware people simply tolerate you")
```

(this was taken from about the middle of my code and the rest of it works)

Comment: What is the problem, is the code not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition should be `"bot" in message.content and "bad" in message.content`. Otherwise Python interprets it as `("bot") and ("bad" in message.content)`, which is equivalent to `(bool("bot")) and ("bad" in message.content)`. Since the [truth-value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of a non-empty string like `"bot"` is `True`, this is equivalent to `(True) and ("bad" in message.content)`, which in turn will always be equivalent to whatever `"bad" in message.content` evaluates to (see the [definition of `and`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)).

Comment: Thnx you legend